# What is the reason C++ doesn't add `std::vector<std::string>` "overload" as argument to `main()`?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point, stdvector

Is there any fundamental reason why the new C++17 (or later) won't allow for an alternative way of writing `main` as

```
int main(std::vector<std::string> args){...}
```

? I know that one needs compatibility with previous code, so

```
int main(int, char**)
```

still has to exist, but is there anything technical that prevents the first "alternative" declaration?

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry I missed the `vector`.

Comment: make it `int main(const std::vector<std::string> &args)`. Yes would be nice getting rid of char*. That's decided: I'm starting my C++ standard just for that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You can move into it, so `const` reference won't save much.

Comment: If you do this, you run into the issue where every single C++ program needs to know about `std::vector`. It's a lot of extra hassle without much benefit. You can always add the contents of `argv` to a vector anyway.

Comment: I don't think there can ever be a *technical* reason this is not supported. Obviously you can write the code that does it, so the runtime could also do the same on your behalf.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson and `std::string` too!!

Comment: The current signature, inherited from C, where it was designed for Unix, is already flawed: it can't handle non-ASCII arguments in Windows. In case any associative fanboy's reading this and feels that all the numerous theoretically possible schemes deserve to be mentioned and somehow disproves the fact: I'm talking about the in-practice, for portable code. So, it would be rather silly and **counter-productive to add an additional non-portable overload**.

Comment: the problem of the C++ from the start is that as opposed to python or C# (and possibly others, maybe Java too), vectors & strings are not in the language but in libraries. And we're dragging that milstone for years.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Well the compiler can be smart enough to add them if you write `main(vector<string>)`, and not add them if you do `main(int, char**)`. C++11/14/17 discourages the usage of raw pointers, but you see them when you first glance at a `main` function.

Comment: @vsoftco let's write C++ 20 together. I'll do the documentation :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: It's already been attempted and is ongoing, twice. First with the D language, then with the Rust language. Both are interesting.

Comment: In passing, while the topic is up: there was a series of articles in ACCU Overload journal about defining a generic main. It involves much more than simply dealing with arguments. One of the most important, for C++, IMHO, is to provide default handling of exceptions.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Do you happen to know which issue?

Comment: Personally I would prefer something akin to Perl's [`Getopt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) which would standardize the reading of command line arguments. I vote for that in C++20.

Comment: @vsoftco: Sorry, I'm unable to find it. I've googled plus I've looked at a number of arbitrary issues spread over the last years. I think it must be named something non-obvious.

Comment: There is really no reason why it *couldn't* be done but I doubt many people would want it. Why tie start up code to library functions? That goes against the original philosophy of the language roots which is to keep the language itself as small as possible. It is trivial to transfer the arguments into a vector if preferred. Personally I would like `int main(char** argv)` because I rarely if ever use `int argc`.

Comment: @Galik But how would you then know the size of `*argv` (except using some delimiter)?

Comment: @vsoftco `argv` is *null-terminated* so you just keep reading until you get a `nullptr`.

Comment: @Galik Oh yes, you're right.

Comment: @Galik: Why do you doubt that? Or rather, given the choice, wouldn't you agree that at least, say, a third of all people who know C++ would rather write their `main()` that way - assuming it was portable and in the standard?

Comment: Because `main()` isn't necessarily called by C++ code. It is basically a bootstrap mechanism and in Unix-derived compilers it is called by `__crt0` or similar, which is the executable's real entry point.

Comment: @einpoklum I don't really have any more reasons for my opinion other than the ones I already mentioned. I could not put a number on how many people might want to use a `std::vector`. For serious command line tools I suspect most use a pre-written argument processing library. For hand written argument processing I did go through a phase of transferring the command line arguments to a `std::vector`, but TBH it didn't make it any easier than using the built-in arrays directly.

Comment: @einpoklum If you follow the `ISO` discussion forums where people debate new proposals for extending the `C++` language I think you will find a great deal of resistance to changes unless it is for something that can't be achieved using library code. I suspect there would be a lot of resistance to making library code inextricably part of the language itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be somewhat non-trivial to implement, at least in one respect.

This basically requires kind of a reverse-lookup form of function overloading. That is, the startup code normally looks roughly like this:

```
extern int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]);

void entry() { 
    // OS-specific stuff to retrieve/parse command line, env, etc.
    static_constructors();
    main(argc, argv, envp);
    execute(onexit_list);
    static_destructors();    
}
```

With your scheme, we'd need two separate pieces of *startup* code: one that calls `main` passing `argc`/`argv`, the other passing a `std::vector<std::string>`.

I should add that while this means the job isn't entirely trivial, it's still far from an insurmountable problem. Just for one example, Microsoft's linker already links different startup code depending on whether you've defined `main` or `WinMain` (or `wmain` or `wWinMain`). As such, it's obviously possible to detect the (mangled) name of the entry point the user has provided, and link to an appropriate set of startup code accordingly.

Comment: To be honest, we already _have_ overloading, and even had it in C: `int main(void)` was an equally valid signature as far back as C89.

Comment: @MSalters: Officially, yes. From a implementation viewpoint, however, it wasn't (normally) like other overloading. In ever case I've seen, the startup code put the arguments there, and it was up to the code to decide whether to use them or not. The compiler got involved to the extent that it had special knowledge to not mangle `main`'s name, but that was about it. This is different: you really need separate startup code, one C-style and the other creating a vector of string. You can't just do one thing and leave it up to the receiving side to decide how to use it.

Comment: I know. I seriously considered submitting this as proposal to WG21, back in 2003. What stopped me was my attempt to get it working in GCC. It's a lot easier to convince the CWG that something is doable when you've actually done it, after all. But I simply did not see a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how to do that yourself, **trivially**, in a very few lines of code:

```
auto my_main( std::vector<std::string> const& args ) -> int;

auto main( int n_args, char** args )
    -> int
{ return my_main( std::vector<std::string>( args, args + n_args ) ); }
```

Modulo notation I believe this approch is presented in the Accelerated C++ book, i.e. it's well known.

One doesn't need to add this to the standard: those who find it useful can just copy and paste the code.

Others may not find it useful: it doesn't work so well in Windows, because by common convention the `main` arguments are not Unicode in Windows, and Microsoft's `setlocale` explicitly does not support UTF-8 locales.

Comment: @vsoftco: Thanks! Fixed. I *really* need a better keyboard…

Comment: That's not trivial at all. The whole point is for the coder to be able to write `main()` this way to begin with...

Comment: @einpoklum: Oh. It *will be* trivial also to you. If you continue to use C++. ;-)